# Select option by value from datalist containing a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, html-datalist

this is my js code

```
$('#AddressStreet').on('keyup', function() {
    let value = $(this).val();
    let optionVal = $('#AddressStreetList option[value*="' + value + '"]').attr('rel');
    console.log(optionVal); //output 'undefined'
    if (!optionVal) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

And this is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" placeholder="street" id="AddressStreet">
```

I am creating a simple datalist using ajax and when I enter to the input `Сам` the datalist looks like this

```
<datalist id="AddressStreetList">
  <option rel="2346" value="ул. Самара"></option>
  <option rel="2444" value="ул. Цар Самуил"></option>
</datalist>
```

I am getting `undefined` from console.log when I try to output it to the console. Also when I use DevTools by Chrome and write this

> $('#AddressStreetList option[value*="Сам"]').attr('rel');

I am successfully getting the desire output which is:

> "2346"

But I don't get it why my code don't want to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a very noob mistake i forgot to put the `list` attribute in my `input` field and that's why it was not working. It should be like that

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" list="AddressStreetList" name="street" placeholder="street" id="AddressStreet">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your option values. If you type another term in value such as value1, value2, example, user, etc. all are working fine. I think your options have a special character that's why it's not working.

Please check the sample code here

```
[https://codepen.io/aalokmali/pen/yWWWdm]
```

Comment: i don't believe this is the problem, as if the work begin with what is typed in the input box it is finding it the correct way, but if what is typed in the input box is somewhere in the mid of the string then for some reason it is not working

Comment: It will work if you just copy Самара or Сам from your data list option value and paste it in the input box. Then it will give you the right result.